# "Не сегодня-завтра" или "не сегодня завтра"?

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Разные источники подают по-разному. Я склоняюсь к написанию через дефис, но всё же хочется услышать авторитетное мнение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грамота - весьма авторитетный источник - утверждает, что дефисное написание устарело, а раздельное написание "не сегодня завтра" зафиксировано в «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН. (см: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: Мне кажется, что такое написание -  просто  прецедент в русской орфографии. Это слово, словосочетание? Какая связь между сегодня и завтра? Можно ли вообще найти в русском языке  что-нибудь подобное? А главное - зачем?  Зачем нарушать правило, которое является обобщенным  для любых повторов (одинаковых слов, синонимов, антонимов, а также слов, связанных между собой по смыслу: "Наречия, образованные повторами, типа чуть-чуть, давным-давно, крепко-накрепко, волей-неволей, мало-помалу, сикось-накось, пишутся через дефис.  ПАС: http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=73#pp73

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос на самом деле. Написание следует рекомендовать именно раздельное. В орфографии и пунктуации русского языка просто нет средств для передачи правильного значения этого устойчивого сочетания. Пусть уж остается без знаков вообще.

**@М_Г**

> Грамота - весьма авторитетный источник - утверждает, что дефисное
>   написание устарело

"Справка" права, раздельное написание больше соответствует современным тенденциям. Но не потому, что "Справка" вдруг стала "весьма авторитетным источником", и даже не потому, что Лопатин "круче" "Розенталя". Просто от безвыходности. Иное написание сильно бы портило впечатление.

Почему не дефис. Если разобраться, смысл этого выражения не в отрицании "сегодня-завтра" а что то наподобие "Не сегодня - так завтра", "если не сегодня, то завтра". То есть отрицание относится не к всему дефисно написанному слову (слова, написанные через дефис с точки зрения орфографии считаются одним словом), но только к первой его части. По современным представлениям такое невозможно (благодаря, кстати, и Лопатину). Раньше на это не обращали внимания и дефис со времен Грота использовали в совершенно немыслимых по современным понятиям случаях. Розенталевское написание "не сегодня-завтра" - один из таких освященных временем нелогичных случаев недавнего прошлого.

Но если не дефис, то что? Не будь это устойчивым сочетанием, уместна была бы запятая или, возможно тире, но именно в устойчивых сочетаниях, фразеологизмах, эти знаки обычно не используются. Так что все правильно, лучше уж без знаком вообще, чем со знаками нелогичными.

**@Arina**

> Мне кажется, что такое написание - просто прецедент в русской
>   орфографии

Прецедентом - вернее сказать "нонсенсом" - было именно дефисное написание. Ваши примеры - без "не". На "Сегодня-завтра" никто не покушается, а вот с отрицанием сразу возникают вопросы. Здесь не действует правило о "повторах", ибо "не" относится только к первой части, то есть дефис надо бы ставить между "не сегодня" и "завтра", но для этого нет ни причин (это уже не "повтор", а нечто другое), ни правила (дефис не ставится между частями, любая их которых, орфографически представляющими из себя более одного слова).

> Можно ли вообще найти в русском языке что-нибудь подобное?

А много вы найдете фразеологизмов с "повтором" и отрицанием? "Не мытьем так катанием"? если написать без "так" подойдет?

*(текст не вычитан, извините, завтра проверю)*