# Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

> Я поменяю все правда только не сегодня завтра

Comment: Вы начните, хотя бы. Помогают тому, кто делает.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. **Я поменяю всё,  правда (поменяю),  только не сегодня ― (а)завтра.**

***Правда*** ― частица со значением уверенности, ***только*** имеет значение союза НО.

Вариант 2. **Я поменяю всё,  правда/только  не сегодня ― (а) завтра.**

***Правда*** в значении союза ХОТЯ, ***только*** в значении союза НО.

Во втором варианте надо   убрать одну из частиц, чтобы исключить две частицы, стоящие рядом.

Обе частицы можно заменить союзом НО, то есть они близки по значению. В тоже время каждая из них имеет дополнительный смысл: ***только*** ― ограничение, ***правда*** ― уступка.

Answer (score 0):

**Я поменяю все, правда, только не сегодня — завтра.**

1. Предложение необходимо начинать с заглавной буквы.
2. Вводное слово [правда](http://%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%B0) (= честное слово) обособляется с двух сторон запятыми.
3. Союз *только* употребляется при противопоставлении; соответствует по значению союзам **но, однако.**
4. При пропуске слова (*только не сегодня, [а] завтра*) и при отношениях противопоставления ставится тире.
5. В конце предложения нужна точка.

Answer (score 0):

*Я поменяю все, правда только не сегодня — завтра.*

так как, если вводное слово стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота, то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется: *Этот элемент входит в состав всех живых организмов, правда в ничтожных количествах.*

Answer (score 0):

**Я поменяю всё, правда, только не сегодня завтра.**

Здесь *правда* играет роль частицы, выражающей уверенное подтверждение. *Сегодня-завтра* пишется через дефис, но в выражении *не сегодня завтра* — без дефиса.

Answer (score 0):

Вспоминается знаменитое "Казнить нельзя помиловать".

Расстановка знаков препинания меняет смысл предложения.

**Я поменяю все, правда, <>** — Я поменяю все, это правда.
**Я поменяю, все правда, <>** — Я поменяю то, о чем говорилось ранее, все это правда.
**Я поменяю все, правда <>** — Я поменяю все, однако ...
**Не сегодня ― завтра.** — Не сегодння, а завтра.
**Не сегодня завтра.** — Не в ближайшее время. (О написании без дефиса см. “[Не сегодня-завтра” или “не сегодня завтра”?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433264/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0))